# Cannot find db record after using mongodb session

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I have a NodeJS code with mongodb and mongoose.

I have an API with a long process so I need to use the transaction, and I have the following code

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const transactionOptions = {
    readPreference: 'primary',
    readConcern: { level: 'local' },
    writeConcern: { w: 'majority' } }

const createModel = async (req, session) => {
    // Process info
    const model = (await Model.create([data], { session }))[0]

    await extraProcess(model, session) }

const extraProcess = async (model, session) => {
    const db_model = await Model.findOne({ _id: model._id }).session(session)
    db_model.key_to_update = new_value
    await db_model.save({ session }) }

export default async (req, service) => {
    const session = await mongoose.startSession({ causalConsistency: true })
    let response
    await session.withTransaction(async () => {
        response = await createModel(req, session)
    }, transactionOptions)
    session.endSession()
    return response }
```

In the second function `extraProcess` when I try to get the created model it returns null.

But locally the feature is working but on the server its not although its the same server configuration.

Do I have an issue with my transaction?